# How to read a CSV file from directory in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv

I have googled for a long time, but have been unable to find the answer to the following question:

Code so far (within larger html file):

```
    var filename = "/Users/FlorisHolstege/Documents/data_weather/"
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    file = request.open('GET', filename, true);
```

I have csv file in my directory ("data_weather"). I want to read this file as an array, but I do not know how to access the content of the file.

Once I can access the content of the file, I can play around and turn it into an array. But currently I am unable to get anything from the file. Console.log(file) results in "undefined".

Any help would be great!

Comment: Don't post a picture of your code. Post the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) + reading from a local directory doesn't work via web.

Comment: Even I am sailing on the same boat. Searched the web for a long time, but still not knowing how to do. Document readystate is not matching. Could oyu please share your answer how you have solved it

Answer (score 3):

Try using query:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "file url",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {console.log(data);}
     });
});
```